# When should "lib" and "include" directories be built when compiling from source?

Tags: compiling, make, cross-compilation

I am trying to build `binutils` on **platform A**, which will be run on **platform A** and targets **platform B**.

I have the source of `binutils` in `/home/cedric/source/binutils-2.29/`, and I perform the following 2 builds:

```
cd /home/cedric/source/
mkdir default/ && cd default/
mkdir build/ install/ & cd build/
../../binutils-2.29/configure --prefix=/home/cedric/source/default/install/
make
make install
```

and

```
cd /home/cedric/source/
mkdir lfs/ && cd lfs/
mkdir build/ install/ & cd build/
../../binutils-2.29/configure --prefix=/home/cedric/source/lfs/install/ --target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
make
make install
```

It turns out that there are 2 more directories in `default/install` than in `lfs/install`, i.e. `lib`, which contains `bfd` and `opcodes` static libraries, and `include`, which contains some headers.

#### My Confusion

Why are these static libraries and headers installed (what are they intended for, since `binutils` tools like `ld` and `as` etc. are already built)? And why do they disappear when building for another platform?

#### Research that I've done yet didn't eliminate my confusion:

`binutils-2.29/configure --help` and `README` in `binutils-2.29/`, `binutils-2.29/binutils/`, and `binutils-2.29/bfd/`

FWIW, I found the following in the configure help, which has something to do with directory it may create and their default value:

```
Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
              [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
              [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/PACKAGE]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you’d expect `lib` to be built (or rather, installed) if there’s a library to install, and `include` if there are headers to install. Usually the two go together (at least for C and C++ libraries).

In `binutils`’ case, the libraries and associated headers are `libbfd` and `libopcodes`, as you mention. `libbfd` is a library used to manipulate object files in a variety of formats, `libopcodes` is a library used to map opcodes to instructions. `libbfd` is installed by default for same-host compilation, but not for cross-compilation, which is why you’re seeing different behaviour in your scenarios. You can see the conditional default in [`bfd/acinclude.m4`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/acinclude.m4;h=0991c2e0120912080817124a6f25d80d3cff0336;hb=HEAD#l62) in the source code. Both libraries should be built in all cases.

You only need `libbfd` if you want to build GDB. If you do want to install it in a cross-compilation scenario, you can tell `./configure` to do so with the `--enable-install-libbfd` option; when you do this, the libraries and header files [will be installed](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/acinclude.m4;h=0991c2e0120912080817124a6f25d80d3cff0336;hb=HEAD#l81) in the appropriate host- *and* target-specific directory (`libbfd` is built for the host but contains target-specific code).

Comment: I find [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/cedric-sun/72be1466c19950e4411edca862bfcbb4) in `bfd/acinclude.m4` and understand why `libbfd` is not build now. But what's the logic behind this conditional installation? Are libraries contained in `lib/` meant to be libraries that could be linked on `target` rather than `host`?

Comment: + thus, if i need these libraries when targeting another platform, a cross-compilation for them using a cross-compiler must be performed explicitly and manually?

Comment: See my updated answer; there’s an option you can use to request installation of the files when cross-compiling, there’s no manual build involved. The logic behind the distinction is that libraries contained in `lib` in the main prefix (`/usr` or `/usr/local`) are intended to be used on the host and work generally; when cross-compiling, the `libbfd` you end up with does run on the host, but is target-specific.